# Connections dropping with Anthos Service Mesh 1.12 and up

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-anthos, google-anthos-service-mesh

I am working with a GKE private cluster. Anthos Service Mesh 1.11 is installed with a different Google project as the fleet project. Since that version of Anthos Service Mesh is not supported, I'm trying to update it to 1.12 or later.
Goal: Update to Anthos Service Mesh 1.12 or later.

The deployed container consists of a Java application that connects to DB2 outside the cluster. This is working with Anthos Service Mesh 1.11.

When I switch to using Anthos Service Mesh 1.12 for the injection, the connection to DB2 has the symptom of being dropped and not working.

I have Google Support engaged but, so far they don't have any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google's support finally got back to me and indicated the issue is fixed in ASM 1.14.4-asm.2. In trying that version, the connectivity is working again, so this was an issue in either the upstream ASM implementation or the further upstream Istio implementation.